# Google Analytics Behaviour Flow data export?

Tags: google-analytics, numbers, export

Is there any way to export data from Google Analytics which contains all the data which is used to create the Behaviour Flow diagram? I.e. numbers, not click-and-point information.

I tried the custom report with **dimensions** set to "previous content group" and "content group" and **metricks** set to "Users" and "Exists", but these give me wildly different numbers...

Any help would be really appreciated!

- bram

Comment: Closest thing is this.  I found the data weird and wasn't able to get it to match up flow wise. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/mcf/v3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to export the behaviour flow. The closest you can get is exporting the navigational summary, found under Behaviour > Site Content > All Pages > Navigational Summary.

The other option is to capture session/client & timestamp information and export the entire flow and re-build the behaviour flow manually with this data.

Comment: Do you see any way to approximate the data via the custom reports?

Comment: What do you mean by approximate the data? What are you trying to achieve?